# how to get particular value in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i wanted to get particular value from array .

`$countries = array("af"=>"Afghanistan","ax"=>"Aland Islands","al"=>"Albania);"`

And i have value in variable

`$country_code="ax";`

Using this variable i want to get array value from array

i am new to php ,thank you

Comment: For php7, you can use `$countries[$country_code]??null`, this will return null if there isn't one in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get it this way

```
$value = $countries[$country_code];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to php documentation:

> Array elements can be accessed using the array[key] syntax.

In your code it will looks like: `$value = $countries[$country_code];`

Also I recommend you to read about arrays in PHP here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php 
your case is explained in 6th example.

Answer (score 0):

just to expand on @B.Mossavari answer, you should check the key is there before extracting the value or PHP will return a undefined index Notice

```
if (array_key_exists($country_code, $countries)) {
    $value = $countries[$country_code];
} else {
    $value = ''; // set value to something so your code doesn't fail later 
}
```

this is my preferred way, but you could also check using `isset($countries[$country_code])` or `!empty($countries[$country_code])`

Comment: A better way of doing it is like this `$value = (array_key_exists($country_code, $countries)) ? $countries[$country_code] : ''`